# How can i hide the iOS Simulator?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm using the console a lot and the Xcode opened me in full screen and every time I press run to see the output in the console its swipe me left and the ios simulator come in the front.

There is way to disable it or something?

I know about the <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> (to build it) but the console wont get out, only run working for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify the Behaviors in the Xcode 4 preferences to show the console on a successful build.

[image]